# C# loop through attributes inside xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to C# but attempting to make an app to parse a simple XML file like shown below and populate the data inside a multi-column ListView.

```
<mods>
<mod Name="mod1.zip" sha1="508ed8f5fcd7d323d9296acad76f1183b810f62a"/>
<mod Name="mod2.zip" sha1="669d8d09d297a9724fe1d1d676ac5f5a8ff10277"/>
</mods>
```

Here is the code I'm trying to work from but it isn't populating the ListView like I'd expect it to..

```
modList.View = View.Details;
modList.Columns.Add("Name", 650);
modList.Columns.Add("Status", 111, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

XElement root = XElement.Load("https://website.com/modlist.xml");
var mods = from subject in root.Descendants()
            where subject.Name.LocalName.Contains("Mod")
            select new
            {
                Name = subject.Element("Name").Value,
                Hash = subject.Element("Hash").Value,
            };

foreach (var mod in mods)
{
    modList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
        {
            mod.Name,
            mod.Hash
        }));

}
```

Comment: You're looking for `Mod` elements, but they're all `mod` elements. You're also looking for *elements* called `Name` and `Hash`, but they're actually *attributes* called `Name` and `sha1`. (It's not clear why you're using `Contains` rather than just using `root.Descendants("mod")` either.)

Comment: your XML element doesnt have an attribute called Hash, instead they are sha1, sha2 per your above code snippet. That could be reason why it wont be finding and populating the Hash property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all mods using [`Descendants("mod")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Descendants_System_Xml_Linq_XName_). And the attribute using [`Attribute("Name")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute?view=netcore-3.1)

```
var mods = from ele in xDoc.Descendants("mod")
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = (string)ele.Attribute("Name"),
                        Hash = (string)ele.Attribute("sha1")
                    };
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tSsjKe)

You can use [`Attributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attributes?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Attributes) to list all the attributes.
If you have to handles Hash  beeing in a  SHA-1, SHA-2 , or SHA-256 attribute